# How to solve Error: Cannot find module 'vue-cli-plugin-vuetify'

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I'm using VueJS version 2.6.12.

Everything fine on my local. It works well. On the other hand, on remote repository(which is checked by a pipeline) it gives this error:

```
> vue-cli-service serve
internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:834
  throw err;
  ^
Error: Cannot find module 'vue-cli-plugin-vuetify'
Require stack:
- /app/node_modules/@vue/cli-service/lib/Service.js
- /app/node_modules/@vue/cli-service/bin/vue-cli-service.js
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:831:15)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:687:27)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:903:19)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:74:18)
    at idToPlugin (/app/node_modules/@vue/cli-service/lib/Service.js:145:14)
    at /app/node_modules/@vue/cli-service/lib/Service.js:184:20
    at Array.map (<anonymous>)
    at Service.resolvePlugins (/app/node_modules/@vue/cli-service/lib/Service.js:170:10)
    at new Service (/app/node_modules/@vue/cli-service/lib/Service.js:32:25)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/app/node_modules/@vue/cli-service/bin/vue-cli-service.js:15:17) {
  code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
  requireStack: [
    '/app/node_modules/@vue/cli-service/lib/Service.js',
    '/app/node_modules/@vue/cli-service/bin/vue-cli-service.js'
  ]
}
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! metronic-vue-demo1@7.2.0 start: `vue-cli-service serve`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the metronic-vue-demo1@7.2.0 start script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /root/.npm/_logs/2021-03-26T20_14_41_033Z-debug.log
ERROR: (gcloud.app.deploy) Error Response: [9] 
Application startup error! Code: APP_CONTAINER_CRASHED
```

There would be some problem with my template. But I can't figure it out what it is.

I have checked `vue-cli-plugin-vuetify` is in my package.json in `devDependencies`.

Here is my package.json

```
{
    "name": "sample-project",
    "version": "1.2.0",
    "private": true,
    "scripts": {
        "serve": "vue-cli-service serve",
        "build": "vue-cli-service build",
        "lint": "vue-cli-service lint",
        "rtl": "webpack --config webpack-rtl.config.js"
    },
    "dependencies": {
        "@babel/polyfill": "^7.4.4",
        "@fortawesome/fontawesome-free": "^5.13.0",
        "@mdi/font": "^3.6.95",
        "@popperjs/core": "^2.4.0",
        "@riophae/vue-treeselect": "^0.4.0",
        "animate.css": "^4.1.0",
        "apexcharts": "^3.19.0",
        "axios": "^0.21.1",
        "axios-mock-adapter": "^1.18.1",
        "bootstrap": "^4.5.0",
        "bootstrap-vue": "^2.13.0",
        "clipboard": "^2.0.6",
        "core-js": "^3.6.5",
        "dayjs": "^1.10.4",
        "deepmerge": "^4.2.2",
        "highlight.js": "^9.18.1",
        "line-awesome": "^1.3.0",
        "object-path": "^0.11.4",
        "perfect-scrollbar": "^1.5.0",
        "portal-vue": "^2.1.7",
        "roboto-fontface": "*",
        "socicon": "^3.0.5",
        "sweetalert2": "^9.10.12",
        "tooltip.js": "^1.3.2",
        "vue": "^2.6.11",
        "vue-apexcharts": "^1.5.3",
        "vue-axios": "^2.1.4",
        "vue-cropperjs": "^4.1.0",
        "vue-highlight.js": "^3.1.0",
        "vue-i18n": "^8.17.4",
        "vue-inline-svg": "^1.3.0",
        "vue-router": "^3.1.5",
        "vue2-perfect-scrollbar": "^1.5.0",
        "vuelidate": "^0.7.5",
        "vuetify": "^2.2.26",
        "vuex": "^3.3.0",
        "zipcelx": "^1.6.2"
    },
    "devDependencies": {
        "@vue/cli-plugin-babel": "^4.5.9",
        "@vue/cli-plugin-eslint": "^4.5.9",
        "@vue/cli-service": "^4.5.9",
        "@vue/eslint-config-prettier": "^4.0.1",
        "babel-eslint": "^10.0.3",
        "eslint": "^5.16.0",
        "eslint-plugin-prettier": "^3.1.3",
        "eslint-plugin-vue": "^5.2.3",
        "sass": "^1.29.0",
        "sass-loader": "^8.0.2",
        "vue-cli-plugin-vuetify": "^2.0.5",
        "vue-template-compiler": "^2.6.11",
        "vuetify-loader": "^1.3.0",
        "webpack-cli": "^3.3.11",
        "webpack-messages": "^2.0.4",
        "webpack-rtl-plugin": "^2.0.0"
    },
    "eslintConfig": {
        "root": true,
        "env": {
            "node": true
        },
        "extends": [
            "plugin:vue/essential",
            "eslint:recommended",
            "plugin:vue/vue3-recommended"
        ],
        "rules": [],
        "parserOptions": {
            "parser": "babel-eslint"
        }
    },
    "browserslist": [
        "> 1%",
        "last 2 versions",
        "not ie <= 10"
    ]
}
```

By the way, both `npm install` and `yarn install` works well on local

Comment: Have you ran `npm install` or `yarn` in your pipeline script? Please provide your `package.json`.

Comment: Yes, npm install is working

Comment: @Aside added `package.json`

Comment: Any updates? I'm facing the same problem

Answer (score -4):

Run:npm i / npm install. That worked for me.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/30789645)